How to Convert an XPath Locator to Chained Locator Using find() and findAll() in Selenide?
I am trying to convert the following XPath-based locator to a chained locator using Selenide's find() and findAll() methods:
ElementsCollection filteredBooks = $$x("//div[@class='rt-tbody']//div[@role='row']/ancestor::div[1][descendant::img]/div[@role='row']//div[4][contains(text(), \"O'Reilly Media\")]/ancestor::div[2]//div[2]//a[contains(text(), \"JavaScript\")]");

The goal is to find all books where the publisher is "O'Reilly Media" and the title contains "JavaScript". However, I need to achieve this using find() and findAll() methods rather than relying on XPath.
I’ve tried to convert the logic but keep encountering errors. For example, when trying something like:
$$("div.rt-tbody").findAll(".row").filterBy(...);
Additionally, if there’s a better way to approach this problem in Selenide, I’d appreciate your insights.

For us to be able to help you, you need to include the relevant HTML so we can create new locators. The URL to the page would also be very helpful. Also, according to the Selenide docs, XPath can be used... why are you choosing to avoid XPath?

Just saying you "keep encountering errors" doesn't help us. We can't guess what the errors were, and how to get around them.
